# Silverlight ValidationSummary omits MessageHeader for Property bound by UserControl

Tags: validation, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, user-controls, dependency-properties

I’ve defined a custom UserControl with DependencyProperty.  My page contains the UserControl, a Textbox, and a ValidationSummary.  Using XAML, the page instantiates the Textbox and UserControl, binding their DependencyProperties to Properties of a single ViewModel.
The ValidationSummary works as expected for the "Request Description" Textbox:

1. MessageHeader (bolded) shows text from bound property’s DisplayAttribute’s Name property.
2. Message (non-bolded) shows text of exception thrown by bound property.

   ```
   <Display(Name:="Request Description")> _
   Public Property RequestDescription() As String
     Get
         …
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As String)
         …
         If value.ToLower.Contains("zombie") Then
             Throw New Exception("We're not saying the zed word.")
         End If
         …
     End Set
   End Property
   ```

However, the ValidationSummary for the "Fleet Unit" UserControl lacks a MessageHeader.

[image: val sum]

When I examine the ValidationSummary’s errors property, I find that the error for the UserControl has:

- MessageHeader=Nothing
- Sources.Count=1
- Sources(0).Control=MyUserControl
- Sources(0).PropertyName=Nothing

In contrast, the error for the Textbox has both MessageHeader and Sources(0).PropertyName matching the DisplayAttribute’s Name property.

I’ve placed a DisplayAttribute with Name on the ViewModel property to which the UserControl is bound.  I’ve tried placing DisplaceAttributes in the UserControl’s DependencyProperty as well as the Property named in the DependencyProperty’s registration.  None of these flow through to the ValidationSummary’s ValidationSummaryItemSource.PropertyName.

Can anyone offer a tip on making ValidationSummary show a MessageHeader for a property bound by a UserControl?

More info (11/2/2011 5:15 PM ET):
Clicking on either of the errors listed in ValidationSummary causes the related control to be focused.  When the Textbox is clicked, the Message is displayed to the right of the Textbox as well as in the ValidationSummary. (Not shown.) When the UserControl is clicked the Message only appears in the ValidationSummary.

More info (11/9/2011 10:14 AM ET):
kmacmahon: Hopefully this what you needed.  Thanks for your help!

```
Function ValidateEntry(ByVal fieldname As String, ByRef value As Object) _
  As Object
    Dim ctx As New ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing)
    ctx.MemberName = fieldname
    Validator.ValidateProperty(value, ctx)
    Return value
End Function
```

.

```
<Display(Name:="Fleet Unit ID")> _
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Fleet Unit is required, but not supplied.")> _
Public Property FleetUnitID As Integer?
    Get
        Return _Incident.EFleetUnitID
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer?)
        Const propname As String = "FleetUnitID"
        If Not Equals(_Incident.EFleetUnitID, value) Then
            If value Is Nothing Then
                _Incident.EFleetUnitID = Nothing
            Else
                _Incident.EFleetUnitID = ValidateEntry(propname, value)
            End If
            NotifyChangeUpdate(propname)
        ElseIf value Is Nothing AndAlso FleetUnitIDRequired Then
            ValidateEntry(propname, value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

.

```
<Display(Name:="Request Description")> _
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Please describe your request.")> _
<StringLength(8000)> _
Public Property RequestDescription() As String
    Get
        Return Incident.RequestDescription
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Const propname As String = "RequestDescription"
        If Not Equals(Incident.RequestDescription, value) Then
            Incident.RequestDescription = ValidateEntry(propname, value)
            NotifyChangeUpdate(propname)
        End If
        If RequestSpecificReference IsNot Nothing _
            AndAlso RequestSpecificReference.Template > "" Then
            If value = RequestSpecificReference.Template Then
                Throw New Exception("Please provide information" _
                      & " requested in description field.")
            End If
        End If
        If value.ToLower.Contains("zombie") Then
            Throw New Exception("We're not saying the zed word.")
        End If
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SubmitButtonVisibility")
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Can you post your property and related attributes for Fleet Unit and the validation exception block for is required?